# How do I change the address of a BME280 sensor?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors

I'm trying to create a sensing station using the BME280 temperature, pressure, and humidity sensor and a raspberry pi. When I run my python code, I receive the error: "RuntimeError: Unable to find bme280 on 0x76, IOError" When I run i2cdetect -y 1, the address the device is on is 0x77. How do I fix this? I'm very new to electronics work, so any and all help is appreciated. My code is below.

```
import time
try:
    from smbus2 import SMBus
except ImportError:
    from smbus import SMBus
from bme280 import BME280

print("""bmeTest.py - Read temperature, pressure, and humidity

Press Ctrl+C to exit!

""")

# Initialize the BME280
bus = SMBus(1)
bme280 = BME280(i2c_dev=bus)

while True:
    temperature = bme280.get_temperature()
    pressure = bme280.get_pressure()
    humidity = bme280.get_humidity()
    print('{:05.2f}*C {:05.2f}hPa {:05.2f}%'.format(temperature, pressure, humidity))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Can you add the full error stack?

Comment: The `BME280` class almost certainly has a parameter for specifying the I2C address; read the documentation, or if all else fails, read the source code.  (I can't give you a specific answer, because I have no idea which of the various modules that are available for this sensor you have installed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to fix this problem.

1. The BME-280 has an SDO line which sets the devices address - 0x76 if connected to Gnd, 0x77 if connected to Vdd. You probably have it connected to Vdd, so you can connect it to Gnd instead.
2. While initializing the BME object you can pass it a parameter to determine its address - `i2c_addr`. The default value is `I2C_ADDRESS_GND` but you can change it: `bme280 = BME280(i2c_dev=bus, i2c_addr=I2C_ADDRESS_VCC)`
   References: [BME datasheet](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/datasheets/bst-bme280-ds002.pdf), [pimoroni module](https://github.com/pimoroni/bme280-python/blob/master/library/bme280/__init__.py)

Comment: Thank you so much! The first solution worked; I really appreciate it.